# Create RandomForest training without splitting the data. I have training data in one file and test data in another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, random-forest, oversampling

I want to try using the random forest classifier in python without using train_test_split. I have a training dataset in one file and I want to train the python machine learning model using the training dataset and then I want to apply the model on the test dataset. All the datasets are in different excel files

I have tried to using SMOTE oversampling but I need to define 'X_train'

from imblearn.over_sampling import (SMOTE, SMOTENC, BorderlineSMOTE,SVMSMOTE,KMeansSMOTE)

sm = SMOTE(sampling_strategy='not majority',random_state=None,k_neighbors=10)
x_train_res, y_train_res = sm.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)

Comment: How do you load your data?

Comment: import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import matplotlib as plt

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

from imblearn.over_sampling import (SMOTE, BorderlineSMOTE, SVMSMOTE, SMOTENC,KMeansSMOTE)


from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler


df=pd.read_excel ("E:\Python_tutorial\Train26082019.xlsx")

Comment: So is your question how to make `df` into `X_train` and `y_train`?

Comment: Actually, I wanted to use one `df1` as the training set and another `df2` as a test set. To go around it, I have replaced the `X_train` and `y_train` by `df1` and `X_test` by `df2`